# Job_run_id for Databricks jobs that only contain 1 task

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

It seems like the task_run_id becomes the run_id for Databricks jobs (Azure) that only have 1 task, whereas the job_run_id becomes the run_id for Databricks jobs that have 2 or more tasks. My question is: Where can I find the job_run_id for Databricks jobs (Azure) that only contain 1 task?

Comment: Are you using databricks on Azure?

Comment: Hi Saideep. Yes, it's databricks on Azure.

Comment: What do you mean by job run id here? Can you provide images for better understanding?

Comment: In databricks you click on "Workflows", click on a job, click on a run (under the "Start time" column), and then you get the "Job run details" on the right side with job id, job run id, started, ended, duration and status information - but here the job_run_id is only present for jobs that contain two or more tasks.

Answer (score 0):

- The `task_run_id` might simply be an indication that a particular job contains only single task. Either it is the `job_run_id` or the `task_run_id`, both indicate the run_id for a job run.
- You can verify this using the jobs run list that can be obtained using Jobs API. Use the following code:

```
import requests
import json

auth = {"Authorization": "Bearer <databricks_access_token>"}

response = requests.get('https://<databricks_workspace_url>/api/2.0/jobs/runs/list', headers=auth).json()
print(response)
```

[image]

- You can navigate to your job run and check that the job's run id and the task_run_id are same:

[image]